# Get the latest file from directory with pattern

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a task that generate HTML reports, for example:

```
Api-Test-Automation-2019-06-23-12-35-54-450-0.html
Api-Test-Automation-2019-06-23-12-38-44-701-0.html
```

I want to get the latest report and send it in the email as attachment.

This will actually attach all files:

`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\newman\htmlreport\*.html`

But I just want to add only the latest created file.

Comment: Can you explain more? what did you try and what exactly the issue?

Comment: well im using this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&ssr=false#overview plugin, with that I want to send the email with attachment   and attachment available here  absolute path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\newman\htmlreport\*.html"

with this approach it will attach all the file, but I just want to attach the latest file only.

Comment: this is what I have try "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\newman\htmlreport*.html" but it actually attach all the file and I just want to attache the latest file only as attachment

Comment: What is the log of the html generation?

Comment: not able to find any logs but here is the file name every time first file "Api-Test-Automation-2019-06-23-12-35-54-450-0.html" and next file "Api-Test-Automation-2019-06-23-12-38-44-701-0.html" in same directory

Now only want to pick the 2nd latest file

Comment: generating with timestamp

Comment: Ok, now I understand, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have 2 HTML reports and you want to send only the last report. you can achieve this goal with a PowerShell task that set a variable with the last file path (add a PowerShell task after the html generation):

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\newman\htmlreports
$files = dir -Filter *.html
$latest = $files | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$lastFile = $latest.FullName
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=latestHtml]$lastFile"
```

Now in the send email task just put the variable `$(latestHtml)`.

Comment: giving me errors on script here is  the screenshot please https://imgur.com/a/7VW8hx4

reports will keep increasing and but I just want to pick the latest one only

Comment: we need to debug it, after the first add: `dir`

Comment: my mistake, I forgot `$`, it should be `$latest.FullName` and I fixed also the last line (to `$lastFile`)

Comment: now 2 errors left

##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.setvariable varaible=latestHtml]C:\Users\wsiteuser_temp\Downloads\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.150.3\work_dir\1\s\newman\htmlreport\Api-Test-Automation-2019-06-23-08-14-20-352-0.html' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
##[error]Required field 'variable' is missing in ##vso[task.setvariable] command.

Comment: its actually able to pick the latest file that part is done now not able to set the variable error is there I guess if you please guide on that too ?

Comment: I had a small mistake, I fixed it, copy again and try now

Comment: found error it is a spell mistake "variable" working in perfect way :) 

cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\newman\htmlreport
$files = dir -Filter *.html
$latest = $files | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$lastFile = $latest.FullName
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=latestHtml]$lastFile"

Comment: first of all thank you so much your previous help, just want to do little modification now I want to get the latest folder path, folder will generate with date and time and want to get the latest folder  and inside latest folder there will be a junit report.

Comment: @MehranShafqat You're welcome! If you have a new question please create a new post :)